# Find a value in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I want to find the 'findbig[1]' value from the bottom in the 'arr' array. But I couldn't find a way.

```js
document.write("<h1>[]</h1>");

let arr = new Array(5)

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i] = parseInt(prompt("int", ""));
}

function secoundBig() {
  var findbig = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a
  });
  document.write("2big: " + findbig[1] + "<br>");

  document.write("<p>2big index: " + arr.indexOf(findbig[1]) + "</p>")
}
secoundBig();
```

---

I finally use this codes. I know it is weird. If you want to give me some advice, plz help me.

```
function secondBig(){
    function filterArr(value){
        return value<=9999999999;
    }
    var existedArr=arr.filter(filterArr);   
    var findbig = arr.sort(function(a,b){return b-a}); 
    
    document.write("2big: "+ findbig[1]+"<br>");

    document.write("<p>2big index: "+existedArr.indexOf(findbig[1])+"</p>")
    }
    secondBig();
```

Comment: The [`Array.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) docs might be of interest, in particular, that it sorts in-place.

Comment: Um, length-2??? Sorting is the most inefficient way to find the min and max values of an array. It also changes the original array so that might be a problem. (hint hint hint)

Comment: I made you a snippet. I assumed arr was a new Array(someNumber)

Comment: Instead of `existedArr=arr.filter(filterArr); ` you can just do `existedArr=[...arr]` to create that new array.